# TreeSelect duplicated options in some browsers

Tags: antd, react-dropdown-tree-select

I used [antD](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/#header) TreeSelect in my form, it's working fine in most machines... in one of my colleagues machine it behaving differently in such a way that when scrolling entries are getting duplicated!!!

[image]

I checked on chrome and Firefox in that machine and it's the same!

What can be the reason? I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue (many duplicate subtrees), but it wasn't browser specific.

The reason mine kept duplicating (especially on expand/collapse of a subtree) was because there were nested, non-unique values/keys (i.e. if two or more items had value/key DFP_KEY).

Not sure if that's your issue, but hope this helps.